# Running maximum of changing array of fixed size

Tags: algorithm, sorting

At first, I am given an array of fixed size, call it *v*. The typical size of *v* would be a few thousand entries. I start by computing the maximum of that array.

Following that, I am periodically given a new value for *v[i]* and need to recompute the value of the maximum.

What is a **practically** fast way (average time) of computing that maximum?

Edit: we can assume that the process is:

1) uniformly choosing a random entry;

2) changing its value to a uniform value between [0,1].

I believe this specifies the problem a bit better and allows an unequivocal "best answer" (which will depend on the array size).

Comment: Even with a very simple aproach you would only need to recalculate the maximum when the value dropping out equals the maximum.

Comment: @maraca, the original maximum in the array itself may be changed. it can be decreased.

Comment: @XiaotianPei yes, but it only decreases when the value you are changing equaled the maximum before. That's my point. So if your values tend to increase the simple aproach could be the best.

Comment: @maraca, on average, it is still linear complexity, which is not very satisfactory.

Comment: @XiaotianPei sure, but if the values are just increasing we have O(1)... in practice it always depends...

Comment: @XiaotianPei: actually, unless I'm mistaken, the simple algorithm maraca described is actually amortized O(1) average case.  The O(N) worst case happens on average once per 2N new elements, if they all follow a uniform distribution.  See my answer for an O(1) average answer that avoids the O(N) worst case for even longer with a small fixed-size PQueue.

Comment: "array of fixed time"?  Do you mean "fixed size"?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a `max-heap` of that array. The element can be index to the array. for every element of the array, you should also have some indexes to the element of `max-heap`. so every time `v[i]` is changed, you only need `O(log(n))` to maintain the heap. (if `v[i]` is increased, it will go up in the heap, if `v[i]` is decreased, it will go down in the heap).

Answer (score 0):

If the changes to the array are random, e.g. `v[rand()%size] = rand()`, then most of the time the max won't decrease.

There are two main ways I can think of to handle this: keep the full collection sorted on the fly, or track just the few (or one) highest elements.  The choice depends on the relative importance of worst-case, average case, and fast-path.  (Including code and data cache footprint of the common case where the change doesn't affect anything you're tracking.)

- Really low complexity / overhead / code size:   O(1) average case, O(N) worst case.
  Just track the current `max`, (and optionally its position, if you can't get the old value to see if it `== max` before applying the change).  On the rare occasion that the element holding the `max` decreased, rescan the whole array.  Otherwise just see if the new element is greater than `max`.

  The average complexity should be O(1) amortized: O(N) for N changes, since on average one of N changes affects the element holding the max.  (And only half those changes decrease it).
- A bit more overhead and code size, but less frequent scans of the full array: O(1) typical case, O(N) worst case.
  Keep a priority queue of the 4 or 8 highest elements in the array (position and value).  When an element in the PQueue is modified, remove it from the PQueue.  Try to re-add the new value to the PQueue, but only if it won't be the smallest element.  (It might be smaller than some other element we're not tracking).  If the PQueue is empty, rescan the array to rebuild it to full size.  The current max is the front of the PQueue.  Rescanning the array should be quite rare, and in most cases **we only have to touch about one cache line of data holding our PQueue**.

  Since the small PQueue needs to support fast access to the smallest *and* the largest element, and even finding elements that aren't the min or max, a sorted-array implementation probably makes the most sense, rather than a Heap.  If it's only 8 elements, a linear search is probably best, too.  (From the smallest element upwards, so the search ends right away if the old value of the element modified is less than the smallest value in the PQueue, the search stops right away.)

  If you want to optimize the fast-path (position modified wasn't in the PQueue), you could store the PQueue as `struct pqueue { unsigned pos[8]; int val[8]; }`, and use vector instructions (e.g. x86 SSE/AVX2) to test `i` against all 8 positions in one or two tests.  Hrm, actually just checking the old val to see if it's less than `PQ.val[0]` should be a good fast-path.

  To track the current size of the PQueue, it's probably best to use a separate counter, rather than a sentinel value in `pos[]`.  Checking for the sentinel every loop iteration is probably slower.  (esp. since you'd prob. need to use `pos` to hold the sentinel values; maybe make it signed after all and use `-1`?)  If there was a sentinel you could use in `val[]`, that might be ok.
- slower O(log N) average case, but no full-rescan worst case:
  Xiaotian Pei's solution of making the whole array a heap.  (This doesn't work if the ordering of `v[]` matters.  You *could* keep all the elements in a Heap as well as in the ordered array, but that sounds cumbersome.)  Re-heapifying after changing a random element will probably write several other cache lines every time, so the common case is much slower than for the methods that only track the top one or few elements.
- something else clever I haven't thought of?